# An example of a Random Variable which is not continuous, discrete, nor mixed

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What examples of r.v. are there which are not continuous, discrete, nor mixed?

Comment: How can you possibly construct a rv which is not $A$,$B$, nor $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Every distribution function is of the type $aF+(1-a)G$ with $F$ discrete, $G$ continuous and $0\leq a \leq 1$.

Comment: [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution)

Comment: @wece not exactly, the question was about a r.v. example.

Comment: Unfortunately, non-measure theoretic treatment of probability theory conflicts with measure theoretic treatment. In the latter, continuous is different from absolutely continuous or having  a density.

Comment: @ To those voting to close this question. Why do you want to close it? Can I improve it?

Comment: I suggest you delete this an post a new question defining the terms continuous random variable and mixed random variable because these are not very standard.

Comment: Let's discuss then the definitions @KaviRamaMurthy: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952498/what-is-a-continuous-random-variable-a-collection-of-definitions

Comment: @kludg I've just made a new question on the definition of continuous variable. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952498/what-is-a-continuous-random-variable-a-collection-of-definitions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following [this link](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Singular_distribution)

Let $X_i$ be iid random variables having Bernoulli distribution with $p=1/2$, $X_i\sim Bernoulli(1/2)$. Then

$$Y=2\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^i}X_i$$

has [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) which is neither discrete, continuous nor mixed.

Comment: Wrong answer. What is your definition of a continuous distribution? The Cantor distribution is continuous (though not absolutely continuous).

Comment: The Wikipedia entry (line 5) says that Cantor distribution is continuous everywhere. Please delete this answer.

Comment: @Kavi The answer is correct and I would not delete it. You don't understand what is continuous random variable.

Comment: The standard definition is the following: $X$ is a continuous random variable if the distribution function is a continuous function. In some pre-measure theoretic texts 'continuous' is wrongly used in place 'having a density function' which is wrong in the measure theoretic model.

Comment: "Pre-measure theoretic" texts are correct, continuous distributions have density functions.

Comment: This is like saying that nobody should learn measure theory because you haven't learnt it. Modern probability theory is modeled by the Kolmogorov's formulation and measure theory is a must for learning the subject.  An authoritative book on probability theory is the one by K L Chung. Please read the definition of continuous distribution in this book.

Comment: I've learned measure theory and it is definitely *not* a must for learning probability theory. I've seen "measure theorists" who were unable to solve simple probability problems.