# What is a continuous random variable? A Collection of definitions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, definition

Although this is a question about what's a continuous random variable, it seems that there are at least 2 definitions being used.

1. The Distribution function is continuous.
2. There exists a non-negative function $f$ such that $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(s) \ ds$

I'm interested in understanding the consequences (limitations/advantages) for using each one, and maybe someone knows other definitions and add them together with an explanation of their consequences.

Comment: The second definition is exclusively by those who have not learned measure theory.  If you want to be up-to-date with probability theory you have to use the first definition. The correct term for 2) is absolute continuity.  2) implies 1) but not the other way.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy maybe you're right, but for e.g. in DeGroot and Schervish I also find the definition 2)... Schervish has known book of Statistics with measure theory.

Comment: A well known example of a distribution function which satisfies 1) but not 2) is the Cantor function.

Comment: In  my opinion the author of that book is causing confusion in the minds of students by using a non-standard definition. I consider this a disservice to the student community.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Are you sure that it comes there as a *definition*? If so then I regret that. Mathematicians can be quite stubborn.

Comment: I fully go along with @KaviRamaMurthy.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Would you like to write an answer? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the measure induced by a random variable $X$, i.e. $\mu(A) := P\{X \in A\}$ for $A$ in the Borel sigma-algebra, then you would say $X$ is a continuous random variable if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

That is if the Lebesgue measure of some measurable set $A$ is $0$, then it must also be true that $\mu(A) = 0$. If $A$ is a singleton, then you know that its Lebesgue measure is $0$. Hence, $X$ cannot have positive probability at any single point if it is continuous. So this is in line with our intuition of how a continuous random variable should look.

If $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, then by the Radon-Nikodym theorem there exists a function $f$ such that

$$\mu(A) = \int_A f\,dx $$

You also know that considering sets of the form $A := (-\infty,z]$ is sufficient to define $\mu$ uniquely. Hence, if we can find a function $f$ such that the following holds for every $z \in \mathbb{R}$ we can declare $X$ to be continuous.
$$F(z) := \mu((-\infty,z]) = \int_{-\infty}^z f\,dx $$
It is no coincidence that $F$ in your second definition is called an absolutely continuous function. You can read more on this at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity

Comment: Standard text on Probability Theory include those by Feller, Chung, Breiman, Ash, Billngsley etc and none of these authors agree with your definition of  a continuous random variable.  Frankly, I think you are misleading probability students. (Nothing personal, of course).

Answer (score 0):

The first definition is the one that is standard. In some pre-measure theory courses the second definition is given and it is hard to see the difference between the two without  aknowledge of measure theory. However, the difference between the two is important and anyone who wants to learn modern probability theory should adapt definition 1).

Comment: Those who learn and teach probability theory use the definition 2. Those who have nothing to do use the definition 1.

Comment: Thanks for useful comments and answers.  I've raised the issue of "adverse and meaningless comments" on [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29249/290189) for your recent Markov chain answer.